# App Store shows notification but no updates available

Tags: iphone, ios

App Store shows notification but no updates available.

Tried closing the App and also restarting phone but no luck.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens occasionally, it just happened to me.  Restart your iPhone, that usually fixes it.

If not:

1. Log out of App Store
2. Restart iPhone by holding down power & home buttons
3. Log back in to App Store

If those don't work, download a free app.  That will often reset the counter.

Comment: I've tried logging out, restarting and logging back in and also downloaded a free App but it's still there.

Comment: Did you restart using the power/home buttons as I described?

Comment: Yes. I had already restarted anyway as I said in the question but I did it again as per your steps but it's still there. I also downloaded a free App.

Comment: ... and tried turning Notifications off and on for App Store in Settings.

Comment: I've seen this work a few times but I'm not sure why: tap the Update button in the App Store app 10 times.  After the 10th time the screen will refresh.  I think this resets the cache.  You are definitely not alone with this issue, it's been a problem since iOS 8.

If it's still a problem, delete all the apps from your device, restart, then add the apps back.

Comment: Where is the update button? I've put screenshots in the question.

Comment: Bottom right, in the tab bar of your second screenshot.

Comment: I see it updating and reloading but the icon is still there.

Comment: That's the extent of my knowledge of how to fix this.  If deleting and reinstalling the apps doesn't work, your options are
1. Back-up the device and reinstall iOS and then your put your backup on.
2. Contact Apple for help (they'll tell you to do what I've already said)
3. Turn off Notifications for the App Store, like you've already done, to avoid seeing it for now
4. Leave it alone and hope that the next iOS bug fix will solve it.

Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned on Automatic Downloads for Updates.

Turning it off brings back the icon so not really a solution but a workaround until it's fixed at least.